# Is "walk" in this sentence correct? Could it be replaced with walks or will walk?

Tags: tense, verbs, singular-vs-plural, verb-forms

> Almost every creature you see, besides the elephants, walk on two legs, like me.

Comment: Should be "walks". "Walk" here is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every - mixing singular and plural in one sentence.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215744/every-mixing-singular-and-plural-in-one-sentence) Also [Every (noun) has done vs Every (noun) have done](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145731/every-noun-has-done-vs-every-noun-have-done)

Answer (score 1):

"**walks**".

> *Every* creature you see **walks**. (Each one walks)
> *All* the creatures you see **walk**. (They walk)

But there are a couple of *other* problems.

Your elephants seem to be walking on two legs! The words '*apart from*' might be less ambiguous than '*besides*'. As FumbleFingers [said](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266788/should-i-use-besides-or-apart-from-in-the-following-sentences) recently, '*To some extent, **besides** is a "positive polarity" element and **apart from** is a "negative polarity" element.*'

> *"every creature you see, besides the elephants"* suggests "**as well as** the elephants."
> *"every creature you see, apart from the elephants*" means "**except** the elephants."

We usually say animals **walk** on so many *feet*, but **have** so many *legs*.
"Almost every creature you see, apart from the elephants, walks on two feet (or "has two legs"), like me."

If the proximity of the plural '*elephants*' and the singular '*walks*' sounds a little awkward, you might re-arrange the sentence:

"Apart from the elephants, almost every creature you see walks on two feet, like me."

That is what many or most people would say. But for the grammar to be ***top-notch***, it should be: "...walks on two feet, *as I do*."

> They **are** two-legged, like me.
>  They **have** two legs, as I do.

"Apart from the elephants, almost every creature you see walks on two feet, as I do."
or
"Apart from the elephants, almost every creature you see has two legs, as I do."